# How do I create a layer by selecting a color, in GIMP?

Tags: color, gimp, layers, selections, shortcuts

I recently heard about an interesting shortcut, in Photoshop, involving holding Alt (I think) while clicking on a color and automatically creating a layer of that color in the image document.

That is, doing this will take every pixel in the graphic that matches the color and add it to a new layer in the layer group; and it is done with a modifier and a single click.

This sounds very useful, as this general procedure is something I will frequently do while doing a hand drawing. However, I'm primarily a GIMP user and plugin writer, and this isn't significant enough to change over.

Does GIMP have a shortcut like that built into it already? Or will I have to write a Python macro or something similar to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Photoshop (I think this is what you are referring to)

1. Use *Select > Color range* to make a selection by colour
2. Do *Layer > New > Layer via copy* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

In GIMP

1. Use the Select by Colour tool to make a selection by colour
2. Do *Edit > Copy* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
3. Do *Edit > Paste as > New Layer in Place*

There's no default shortcut in GIMP for the last operation, but you could easily set one up in the keyboard shortcuts using *Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts*.

Note: You can't skip the copy step in GIMP because it has no direct one click equivalent to *Layer via Copy* in PS. The result is exactly the same though, but requires two operations instead of one.

Could you script it or create a plugin? Possibly, but what would be the point? To save one keypress seems hardly worth the trouble. But sure, knock yourself out!

Comment: Thanks, I might do it just to remind myself how to use Python in GIMP. (For image stuff, C is much faster; so I may have gotten Python-lazy.) The only reason I might do this is if I was working on several pieces in a single day on a deadline; then the biggest problem with multi-step processes is that they can be a bit of a distraction. Separating things with just a single click, like the shortcut I was referring to, just makes my mouth water.

Comment: "Edit > Paste as > New Layer in Place" can also be done with Ctrl-V, Ctrl-Shift-N.